# create a data grid based on entity attribute values

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working on a MVC5 ASP.net project using C#. I need to create a data grid in a view, from a list of entities where the column and row headers of the grid are dynamic.

Example:

List of entities

```
name  school age
------------------
name1  sch1   10
name2  sch2   15 
name3  sch3   9
name4  sch2   10
name5  sch1   15
name6  sch1   14
...
```

Required view:

```
    sch1     sc2     sch3
--------------------------
 9                  name3
10  name1   name4 
14  name6    
15  name5   name2
```

The school names and ages cannot be predefined in this scenario.

Any suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible to do data pivot first? For example, if your entities come from database, you can do pivot in database to generate a table format looks like your view. Otherwise, you might need some code to convert, either javascript or vb/c#.net

Comment: Thank you for the answer @John Jin . What would you think complies with OO principles of EF and MVC5 best?